# What does "It's got nothing to do with reality" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Schindler's List (1993)*, Czurda ordered Oskar's workers to shovel snow:

> CZURDA: You shouldn't think of them as yours, Oskar. You need to
> understand that some of the officers here don't give a damn about
> production. To them, it's a matter of national priority that Jews be
> made to shovel snow. **It's got nothing to do with reality**, Oskar. You
> know it and I know it. Jews shoveling snow, it's got a ritual
> significance.

What does "It's got nothing to do with reality" mean?

I think he means, “it does not have to make sense.” Or “we want them to shovel snow because we want power over them, not because the snow needs to be shoveled”

Honestly not sure about that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct.

Czurda is saying that the shovelling of snow has no practical purpose. It achieves nothing useful.

The aim is merely symbolic, to impress upon those concerned the inferior status to which they have been reduced.